# Execute Jenkins Pipeline step only when available on Jenkins instance

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We are building our product using a Jenkins Multibranch project defining a `Jenkinsfile` for build-instructions.

Part of the steps are supporting calls to external services using Jenkins plugins. Examples for such calls are `slackSend` to inform the dev via slack of complete/failed jobs or `step([$class: 'StashNotifier'])` to inform Stash/Bitbucket reg. build-results.

The same project is now supposed to run as a fork on another team/Jenkins instance with possibly not having the mentioned Slack/Stash or other integrations.

How can I achieve to not have the Jenkins job fail as of the lack of the upper mentioned plugins?

1. Is there a possibility to see if a given step is available from within the `Jenkinsfile`?
2. Looking for the possibility to set properties as part of the Multibranch Pipeline Configuration itself, I unfortunately did not find anything. If possible, wher is the place to set multibranch pipeline wide environment variables?
3. Is it possible to custom built-in conditions, as e.g. existing for branches `when { branch 'master' }` (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)

Thanks for your support, any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

surround it with catchError:

```
catchError {
  slackSend ...
}
```

Btw, you don't need to take care of the stash notifier at all if you use the [Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin). This will make your build status appear in Bitbucket without further ado.

Comment: Hi Hendrik, thanks for that quick response and the push into the right direction. I now use a `try { ... } catch (err) { }` around the calls in question, as `catchError` would also set the build to fail. Not as declarative as hoped for, but should be okay.